# vba macro list box not letting editing some macros

Tags: vba, excel, menu, ribbon

I have an Excel project with a lot of macros.
What I want is assign macros to buttons in the ribbons.
For that I created macros like:

```
Sub R10_parallel_device()
help.helpON ("parallel_device ")
Call sub_novelty_claims("parallel_device")
End Sub
```

So the three conditions are met:
a) the macro `SUB R10_parallel_device()` do not accept parameters
b) it is not private
c) It is not hide

when I go to the list of macros I see all the list of macros named Rnn but all THE BUTTONS ARE GREY OUT EXCEPTFOR CREATE.
Now if I click in that sub for instance `SUB R10_parallel_device()` I can not edit it and if I click "create" excel sends me to a new created module where 
    Sub R10_parallel_device()

```
End Sub
```

appears.

&
When I go to file/options/ribbon if I want to add that macro to a button it is listed and it is possible to assigne the macro to a button but it would not run, giving the error that such a macro is not found.

NOTE: I checked which macro are listed thisworkbook/all/ etc.
note2: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234838/macros-not-showing-up-in-macro-table) did not help me. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922417/macros-not-showing-up-in-the-run-macro-menu) neither

thx

[image]

Comment: Change the macro names - I'm pretty sure `R` + a number is reserved for something else in VBA. Try renaming them to something different and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed it's the macro names - go to Developer -> View Code (or type Alt + f11), then select the module with your code in it and rename them. For whatever reason it's that `R#` syntax:

[image]