# Assigning Key to Macro

Tags: excel, vba

My real motivation for writing this was [Macros Not Showing Up in Macro Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234838/macros-not-showing-up-in-macro-table). But the macro question is really just a plain vanilla Sub located in a Module file. Literally:

```
Public Sub LaunchRecognia()
    GetRecogniaFactory.GetRecogniaVm(ThisWorkbook).ShowForm
End Sub
```

Thinking it might be a security issue but I doubt it (see below).

However the only reason I wanted the dialog was just to assign a shortcut key, so thought I might see if anyone knows how to do this in code while I'm at it.

Any ideas to troubleshoot the macros not being available? Code to assign shortcuts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the macro setting to "Enable All" ?

Comment: Just curious, but you don't happen to have `Option Private Module` at the top of your module, do you? This would cause the Macro not to be visible on your list....

Comment: @Xabier. No, just Option Explicit,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a corrupted workbook. NO surprise there but the corruption was difficult to detect!

The workbook had a custom ribbon, with a code module to support it. The code module must have been inadvertently deleted. BUT the code still worked, am surmising that the ribbon must somehow embed the code in binary form.

Moved all sheets and code to a new workbook, recreated the missing module, and all's well with visible macros.

Still would love to know if there is a way to programatically assign a key code tho...